# Java Selenium FindBy cannot find div by unique class name

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium with Java and I have encountered issue that I am unable to find div by class name, even though it is unique:

`<div class="123123-randomclassname"></div>`

I am able to find any other element, e.g. input, button, etc. I have issues with div tag only.

I have tried getting this web element using either @FindBy() annotation and findElement() method:

`driver.findElement(By.className("123123-randomclassname"))`
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='123123-randomclassname'"))`

`@FindBy(className = "123123-randomclassname")`
`@FindBy(css = "div[class='123123-randomclassname'"`)

Any of these solutions did not work and I couldn't find element.

Comment: css selector seems invalid. missing `]` and if `randomclassname` is random value then how  this will be unique.

Comment: @KunduK Hey, missing bracket is not fixing the issue. Also, randomclassname is actually just an example, it's not random normally, sorry for the misdirection.

Comment: Check if this element/ div tag is inside the iframe. if yes then switch to that particular iframe and then find the element.  it would be helpful to debug the issue if you could share the parent element tag also.

Comment: This particular div has section tag and another 8 divs before. Each div has its own unique class name and I cannot reach any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class^='123123-']"))
```

Comment: This one did not help. I got exactly the same result, the web element cannot be clicked.

Comment: Do you have any other idea how can I find this particular element, and why it is not working for any div?

Comment: I am afraid without knowing the actual html, is it possible to share the url of the application?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share that. I need to operate on some example data.

Answer (score 0):

//@ and ]closing bracket was missing in syntax
WebElement DivTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@class='123123-randomclassname']"));
//OR
@FindBy(xpath = "div[@class='123123-randomclassname']") WebElement DivTag2;

Comment: Tried making this in many ways, I can use xpath only when I start from id, not working for class name.